# integerForKey always crashes app

Tags: objective-c

Retrieving a value from **standardUserDefaults** using **integerForKey** after saving with **setInteger:forKey** always crashes app.

If I retrieve value using **objectForKey** and cast value to int, there are no errors and I can display value in a log message fine. However, when I attempt to assign that int to another int or try to perform a math function on it, like adding, it crashes app as well.

How do I retrieve an int that I've saved to standardUserDefaults? I'm developing against SDK 3.0 but have experienced identical issue in 2.2.1. Thanks.

prefs defined as

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs;
```

and retrievePrefs always called before savePrefs. App also calls [prefs synchronize] before exiting.

```
-(void)retrievePrefs {
    prefs = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] retain];
    if (prefs) {
       // doesn't crash app, spits out 'page: 1'
       NSLog(@"page: %@", [prefs objectForKey:@"pageIndex"]); 

       // crashes app with no details
       NSLog(@"page: %@", [prefs integerForKey:@"pageIndex"]); 
    }
}


-(void)savePrefs {
    if (prefs) {
        [prefs setInteger:1 forKey:@"pageIndex"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second NSLog call is what's causing it: the `%@` qualifier is used to print out Objective-C objects or CoreFoundation CFTypeRefs, so it's interpreting that integer as a pointer and attempting to dereference it.

What you need is:

```
-(void)retrievePrefs {
    prefs = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] retain];
    if (prefs) {
        NSLog(@"page: %@", [prefs objectForKey:@"pageIndex"]);
        NSLog(@"page: %ld", (long)[prefs integerForKey:@"pageIndex"]);
    }
}
```

Check the API documentation for `NSLog`, `printf`, and `-[NSString stringWithFormat:]` for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the amazingly quick and correct response! 

The (long) did the trick. I tried using (int) before but that didn't help and the app continued to crash. Would you mind explaining the difference between long and int as it relates to setInteger:forKey and integerForKey?

Thanks again! Have been butting my head against this issue for a bit.

Comment: ok thanks. looks like the log statement was indeed causing the crash and i was mis-attributing the crash to other things, like integerForKey not working properly.

Comment: The setInteger: uses the NSInteger type, which is defined as a 32-bit integer in 32-bit apps and a 64-bit long in 64-bit apps; i.e. it's always the size of a processor register.

As regards the cast, casting to long will yield a 32-bit value in 32-bit processes, and a 64-bit value in 64-bit processes, therefore it will match the size of NSInteger. It's also precisely what Apple recommends for passing NSInteger or NSUInteger to a printf-style function.